# How to do a HTTP POST to a URL having SSO Authentication in Java or vbscript?

Tags: java, vbscript, automation, http-post, single-sign-on

I am planning to do automated testing of post requests with various parameters on a link. The problem that I face is the link has a sso authentication. When I do a normal post in vbscript or java it directs me to the sso page.

Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are working with http-post, I assume that SSO is performed by using Cookies.

In that case, everything you have to do is add those Cookies to your request.
This is done by adding a Header with name 'Cookie' to your request.
This headers value may be of the format 'CookieName=CookieValue'.
In case you have multiple Cookies, you can either add multiple Cookie Headers, or separate them by using a ';'.

In case you fetch those Cookies with a previous request, you can get a hold of the Cookies by evaluating the 'Set-Cookie' Header.

[Additional Informations about basic Cookie Handling may be found here](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)

In case you use Apaches HTTP-Components, you can also use its integrated Cookie Store to automatically add Cookies to new Requests.

[A good example as how to basically use Apaches HTTP-Client can be found here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)

The part of how to use Cookies can be found in section 3